# A regular expression for the language $L=\{w \in \{a,b\}^*:n_a(w)=3 \land n_b(w)=4\}$

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions, finite-automata

A language like $L=\{w \in \{a,b\}^*:n_a(w)=3 \land n_b(w)=4\}$ is given.

The first question : Is this language regular?
The second question : If $L$ is regular, How can we write a regular expression for it?
The third question : If i change $L$ to $L'=\{w \in \{a,b,c\}^*:n_a(w)=3 \land n_b(w)=4\}$ , Answer the first and the second question about it.

Note : Generally i know how to write regular expression for a language. But in this case, i can't even draw a DFA for L so that i can convert it to regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$L$ is finite, so it’s certainly regular: it consists of all $7$-letter words over $\{a,b\}$ that contain exactly $3$ $a$s and $4$ $b$s. There are $\binom73=35$ such words. One regular expression for the language simply lists all $35$ of these words in a long disjunction:

$$aaabbbb+aababbb+aabbabbb+\ldots+bbbbaaa\;.$$

$L'$ is still regular: a word is in $L'$ if and only if what’s left after you delete all of the $c$s in it (if any) is one of the $35$ words in $L$. Equivalently, $L'$ consists of all of the words that you can get by starting with a word in $L$ and adding zero or more $c$s anywhere in that word. That approach gives you one (admittedly ugly) regular expression for $L'$.

Comment: @Arman: You’re welcome.